# editar datos de una base de datos desde php con un formulario

Tags: php, html, sql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una base de datos simple que consiste en poder agregar, editar y eliminar datos de sa misma, por ahora funciona el agregar y eliminar datos, lo que no funciona es el codigo de editar.php, a la hora de editar una fila, el formulario se envia pero no me da ningun error, ya sea en el editor de codigo o en la misma pagina

Este es mi codigo:

editar.php

```
<?php
include ('db_conn.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE id_alumno='".$_GET["id_alumno"]."'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$info_alumno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

$nombre = $info_alumno['nombre'];
$apellido = $info_alumno['apellido'];
$nacimiento = $info_alumno['nacimiento'];
$direccion = $info_alumno['direccion'];
$telefono = $info_alumno['telefono'];
$email = $info_alumno['email'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <form action="datos.php" method="POST">
                <h2>Editar el perfil del Alumno</h2>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre; ?>"> <br> <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="apellido" value="<?php echo $apellido; ?>"> <br> <br>
                <input type="date" name="fecha" value="<?php echo $nacimiento; ?>"> Date <br> <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Direccion" name="direccion" value="<?php echo $direccion; ?>"> <br> <br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Telefono" name="telefono" value="<?php echo $telefono; ?>"> <br> <br>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"> <br> <br>
                <input type="submit" id="editar-alumno" name="editar-alumno" value="Enviar">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['editar-alumno'])){
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $naciemiento = $_POST['fecha'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $editar = "UPDATE alumno 
    SET nombre = '$nombre', apellido = '$apellido', nacimiento = '$nacimiento',
     direccion = '$direccion', telefono = '$telefono', email = '$email' WHERE alumno id_alumno=$id_alumno";
     $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $editar);
     header("Location: Alumno.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: y donde definis $id_alumno?

Answer (score 1):

Veo 2 problemas con tu código:

1. La más importante, es que tu código actualmente es vulnerable a ataques de [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL), que es una vulnerabilidad que te expone a un atacante que quiera destruir o manipular la información de tu sitio. Te invito a visitar la pregunta [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/21) para informarte sobre el tema.
2. En ningún lugar defines la variable `$id_alumno`, que utilizas en la sentencia de actualización de la base de datos, por lo tanto, no se actualiza ningún registro. Por la forma en la que está hecho el formulario, podrías obtener esa variable del arreglo `$_GET`, aunque a mi se me hace *mejor* incluirla dentro del formulario, como un campo oculto, y obtenerla, junto al resto de datos, del arreglo `$_POST`. Sin hacer muchos cambios, podría ser algo como:

   ```
    if(isset($_POST['editar-alumno'])){
        $id_alumno = $_GET["id_alumno"];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        //etc
   ```
3. Escribes primero el documento HTML y finalmente verificas si se trata de un post. En esta rutina, intentas hacer un redireccionamiento mediante un header. Sin embargo, la función `header()` tiene efecto solamente cuanto se llama antes de escribir el primer caracter del documento. Así, tendrías que cambiar el orden y la estructura, para que el documento se escriba solamente si no se trata de un post o, por ejemplo, si hay algún error.

   Básicamente algo así:

   ```
    <?php
    $msg_error = "";
    $se_actualizo = False;
    include ('db_conn.php');
    if(isset($_POST['editar-alumno'])){
      //hacer actualización de base de datos
      //dejar mensaje de error al ocurrir algún problema
      //si no hay problema, poner variable $se_actualizo = True;
      if ($se_actualizo) {
        header("location: Alumno.php");
      }
    }
    if (!$se_actualizo) {  //este if se va a quedar abierto
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE 
      id_alumno='".$_GET["id_alumno"]."'";
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
      //seguir con rutina para obtener datos
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
    <!-- seguir con el formulario -->
    <!-- no olvidar imprimir el mensaje de error, si hubo alguno -->

    <?php
    } //terminar la llave del if que se quedó abierto
    ?>
   ```

   El código no pretende ser perfecto, sino mostrarte una estructura más adecuada para lo que quieres lograr. Hay muchas posibles mejoras; para poner un ejemplo, si hay un error podrías rellenar otra vez el formulario con los datos que ya puso el usuario, en lugar de los que están almacenados en la base de datos, para no hacerle perder trabajo.

   En fín, hay muchas posibilidades que quedan fuera del alcance de esta respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu problema reside en las sentencias para hacer la petición a la base de datos que es alojado en `$sql`, pienso que manejas los datos de forma correcta, por ejemplo si haces la peticion usando `mysqli` y devuelve los datos correctos entonces puedes editarlos.

```
// chequear conexión erronea
if ($conexion->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}
```

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE id_alumno='".$_GET["id_alumno"]."'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$info_alumno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
```

Luego deberías usar una sentencia para que a través de `mysqli` se guarden los datos actualizados editados anteriormente en el *script*, el valor de la cadena puede ser algo así `$sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname = '$firstname', lastname = '$lastname', username = '$username', password = '$password', email = '$email'  WHERE id = '$userid';"` y después `$conn->query($sql);`

Answer (score -1):

Debes declarar e inicializar tu variable $id_alumno con el valor que obtienes aqui ----> $_GET["id_alumno"]